# Find All Capital Letter in a String - Regular Expression C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I need to find all **capital letters** in a `string`. For example

**Input** : `Electronics and Communication Engineering`

**Output**: `ECE`

Comment: Very interesting! You may want to try something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you insist on *regular expressions*:

```
 string source = @"Electronics and Communication Engineering";

 string result = string.Concat(Regex
   .Matches(source, "[A-Z]")
   .OfType<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value));
```

*Linq* is a (shorter) alternative:

```
 string result = string.Concat(source.Where(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'));
```

**Edit:** If "capital letters" include *all* Unicode capital letters, not only English, but, say, Russian ones, *regular expression* will use a different pattern

```
 string result = string.Concat(Regex
   .Matches(source, @"\p{Lu}")
   .OfType<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value));
```

and *Linq* solution will use a different condition:

```
 string result = string.Concat(source.Where(c => char.IsUpper(c)));
```

Comment: Which is more efficient? Regular Expressions or Linq?

Comment: @Christlin Joseph: probably, *Linq* (in the context) since it's direct

Comment: An even shorter way is: `string result = string.Concat(source.Where(char.IsUpper));`

Comment: @dnl-blkv: `char.IsUpper(c)` is a bit different condition than `c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'`: the first satisfies *all Unicode* upper case letters (say, Russian ones) when the second satisfies *English* capital letters only. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 9):

Linq Solution [Example is here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iHaCaB):

The extension method `Where` will helps you to get the capital letters from the given string. You can use either `String.Join` or `String.Concat`(nicer as suggested by *DmitryBychenko*) for getting the final output as a string. Go through the following snippet

```
string inputStr = "Electronics and Communication Engineering";
string outputStr=String.Concat(inputStr.Where(x=>Char.IsUpper(x)));
Console.WriteLine(outputStr);
```

Comment: `string.Concat(value)` is a shorter version of `String.Join("", value)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Waw really nice, Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ:

```
string text = "Electronics and Communication Engineering";
var capitalLetters = text.Where(c => char.IsUpper(c)).ToArray();
```