# I need a filtering program in c#

Tags: c#

I need a program that will filter out and show only capital letters from a string. I have an example string:

> c5hDF(5HА_Z*u1BP

I'm supposed to get:

> DFHAZBP

I tried this:

```
string a = Console.ReadLine();
```

I couldn't use 'a' in an IF statement because there is an error that says

> Error CS0200  Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned
>   to -- it is read only

I tried doing it a very long way because I can't think of another way. I basically told the program to check every part of the string if it is a capital letter like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] = "Q")
    {
        b = b + a[i];
    }   
}
```

I was thinking about doing it for every letter but it doesn't work. Also I tried:

```
string v = a;
```

and then type v in all the 'if's' but that didn't work either.

Comment: You could do `var b = new string(a.Where(char.IsUpper).ToArray())`.

Comment: @ckuri you should make this to an answer

Comment: dupe target [Find All Capital Letter in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363153/find-all-capital-letter-in-a-string-regular-expression-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find All Capital Letter in a String - Regular Expression C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363153/find-all-capital-letter-in-a-string-regular-expression-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple typo:

```
if (a[i] = "Q")
```

should be

```
if (a[i] == "Q")
```

for a comparison, not assignment.

Comment: Use `== 'Q'`, single quotes for chars, double quotes for strings.

Comment: @TheDemonCrusher A String is in double quotes e.G. "Q", a Char is in single apostophes, e.G. 'Q', so you should do if (a[i] = 'Q')

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn, and the `==` is gone once again

Comment: Nvm did it i had to use 'Q' not "Q"

Answer (score 1):

Like AKX said you just have a simple typo.

However, it seems like you intend do check every string character against A, B, C, and so on, which is very cumbersome and not really needed. The framework already has [char.IsUpper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isupper) to check if a character is an uppercase letter.

Also instead of a loop you could use LINQ to simplify your code:

```
var b = new string(a.Where(char.IsUpper).ToArray());
```

For `a = "c5hDF(5HА_Z*u1BP"` this yields `b = "DFHАZBP"`.

This takes your string `a` and turns it via LINQ to a sequence of characters, then filters these on if they are uppercase, converting the filtered sequence to an array, which can then be used by using a [string constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor) to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the IsUpper() for your desired output. I have tried the code as per your requirements. Kindly refer the following code.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "IsHanKsHaH";
            char[] charArray = text.ToCharArray();
            foreach(var ch in charArray)
            {
                if(Char.IsUpper(ch))
                {
                    Console.Write(ch);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

The output will be **IHKHH**

Comment: You don't need the call to `ToCharArray` as enumerating a string automatically creates an enumerable of chars.